# Instalação de rvm no windows 7

Tags: windows, ruby, rvm

É possível instalar **rvm** ou **rbenv** no windows 7, para controle de versões de ruby e gems. Se é possível como faço para instalar na minha máquina? ... já segui vários tutorias que instalação de rvm, mas não funcionam, preciso de algo funcional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em qualquer versão do Windows é necessário instalar o:

- https://cygwin.com

ou o:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about

Então instalar as chaves:

- https://rvm.io/rvm/install#install-gpg-keys

Então depois disto instale a versão instavel do RVM com o comando no (terminal do cygwin ou windows sub sustem):

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta resposta Guilherme Nascimento